# Effect of domain on SEO?

Tags: seo, domains

I have a website for student submitted college ratings that focuses on the fun aspects of the colleges (how are the parties, social life, etc).
I currently own 4 different domains and debating which one to use:
funcampuses.com
fun-colleges.com
funcollegecampuses.com
funcollegeratings.com

I like the first one because its catchy and has no spaces, but campuses isn't really a keyword for me - colleges definitely is. Second one is good, but is the dash going to hurt me? funcolleges.com is unavailable.. The 3rd and 4th ones are simply long..

What do you guys think? Thanks!

Comment: @John, I don't think this is "too localized". Although Aviv is asking for advice on specific domains, it's easy to extrapolate this (and my answer) to the general case.

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen isn't a huge problem but they are slightly more complex for users and you don't get any bonus from exact match domains. This was discussed in a [recent Stack Overflow podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/se-podcast-12/) so give that a listen.

If campus isn't your main keyword then ignore #1. Ignore #2 because of the hyphen. Out of the rest, choose whichever would be easier to remember. Neither are too long but they are getting close.

Choose one that rolls off the tongue a little better and makes grammatical sense as a phrase. For example "collegeratingsfun.com" would probably not make sense.

Finally, if funcolleges.com is your ideal domain, you should try and buy it, if it's available for sale. It is probably worth spending a little more for a better domain in the long run.

Comment: well campus is a main keyword, because I am rating how fun the campuses are, however campus isn't really searched for, therefore college is more of a top keyword... i am kind of leaning toward the second one - how bad is it having a hyphen?